# Matrix of type int using uint8_t data prints wrong when passed to a function

Tags: c, function, matrix, int, uint8t

Ok so I got the following pointer sh and the array of matrices shadows.

```
 uint8_t * sh;
 int shadows[k][330][210];
```

I fill the shadows like this:

```
int rows = 165;
int cols - 105;
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){              
            shadows[reached][i][j] = sh[index];
            index++;
        }
}
```

Then I can print for example shadows[0] like this:

```
int i;
int j;
for (i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for(j=0; j<cols; j++){
            printf("%d  ", shadows[0][i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

Everything ok so far. The print of shadows[0] looks fine.
Then I pass this matrix to a function like this:

```
separateMatrixByColumn(1, cols-1, rows, cols, shadows[0], v[0], g[0]);
```

Inside of that functions the first thing I do is print the matrix shadows:

```
void separateMatrixByColumn (size_t wanted_cols1, size_t wanted_cols2, size_t rows, size_t columns, int m[rows][columns], int answer1[rows][wanted_cols1], int answer2[rows][wanted_cols2]){

    // this print looks bad. It adds several 0s to the matrix!
    int k;
    int l;
    for (k=0; k<rows; k++){
            for(l=0; l<columns; l++){
                printf("%d  ", m[k][l]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }

   ...

}
```

Turns out the print inside of my function looks bad. It shows several 0s inside of my matrix. Why is this happening?

Comment: In the declared argument list of `separateMatrixByColumn`, you have `int m[rows][columns]` which isn't right.  `rows`  and `columns` need to match the values in the declaration, not the values of the elements you're actually using.  So they need to be 320 and 210.  (Actually the first dimension can be smaller, but anything after that has to match exactly.)  The other arrays may have similar problems.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I made my matrix bigger bcI I have two possible sizes. Anyways I use an auxiliar matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an additional amtrix

```
  int aux[rows][cols];
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++){
            for(j=0; j<cols; j++){
                aux[i][j] = shadows[0][i][j];
            }
    }
    separateMatrixByColumn(1, cols-1, rows, cols, aux, v[0], g[0]);
```